# Can prototype set function linkage?

Tags: c++

```
// A.h
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

extern "C" void mylib_foo(int);

#endif // A_H
```

```
// A.c

#if INCLUDE
#    include "A.h"
#endif

void mylib_foo(int i)
{
    return i+i;
}
```

If I generate a library with `A.c`, will the two shared librairies compiled with the macros `INCLUDE=0` and `INCLUDE=1` be identical or not?

Briefly, can a prototype influence a function behavior/signature?

Case #2:

```
extern "C" void mylib_foo(int i); // extern "C" prototype
void mylib_foo(int i); // not extern "C" prototype

void mylib_foo(int i) // is mylib_foo mangled or not ?
{
    return i+i;
}
```

Case #3:

More complicated case: if I have another `B.c` file, also part of the library that always includes `A.h`, if latter answer is true, will also `mylib_foo` be `extern "C"` even if `INCLUDE=0` (that is `mylib_foo` definition in `A.c` never "shows" that it is `extern "C"`) ?

Comment: The library with `INCLUDE=0` will have mangled names, the library with `INCLUDE=1` will have non-mangled names.

Comment: `A.c` will be compiled as C, so it is fine.  You can't include a .h file there that contains `extern "C"`, you'd have to wrap it with `#ifdef __cplusplus`. Which is very common.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler Explorer says it can (gcc/clang): https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/n1Mv5M

If there's an `extern "C"` prototype before the definition, the symbol isn't mangled and vice versa.
(CE shows demangled symbols -- functions symbols will show parameter types exactly iff the symbol mangles those types in.)

Putting the prototype in a separate header won't make a difference considering that `#include` works textually.

Comment: But what about the conditional `#if INCLUDE`?

Comment: Is it also the case if the shared library has multiple files ? (question edited)

Comment: @rafoo If the symbols is extern-C-attributed via a prototype, it won't be mangled (in neither the definition or in references) and vice versa. A shared library is just a bunch of object files linked together. You can have one some object file (inside your lib) where foo is mangled and some where it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

- An `extern "C"` declaration that precedes a definition without a linkage specification is valid.

  ```
  extern "C" void f();

  void f() { /* ... */ }  // defines `void f()` with `external "C"` linkage  --  (a)
  ```
- A declaration without a linkage specification that precedes an `extern "C"` definition is illegal.

  ```
  void f();  //or:  `extern void f();`

  extern "C" void f() { /* ... */ }  // error                                --  (b)
  ```

From the Notes on the [Language linkage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/language_linkage) page.

> A function can be re-declared without a linkage specification after it was declared with a language specification, the second declaration will reuse the first language linkage. The opposite is not true: if the first declaration has no language linkage, it is assumed "C++", and redeclaring with another language is an error.

This follows from [dcl.link #6](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.link#6).

> **(b)**   Except for functions with C++ linkage, a function declaration without a linkage specification shall not precede the first linkage specification for that function.
>
> **(a)**   A function can be declared without a linkage specification after an explicit linkage specification has been seen; the linkage explicitly specified in the earlier declaration is not affected by such a function declaration.